# Is there a way to derive/prove that $ \langle Ux, t \rangle = \langle x, U^{-1}t \rangle$ is true for unitary transformations?

Tags: functional-analysis

**Why** is it that $ \langle Ux, t \rangle = \langle x, U^{-1}t \rangle$ is true for unitary transformations?

I have a argument (not quite a proof I guess) of why that is true for finite vectors but I don't know how to generalize it to vectors with infinite dimensions (as in functional analysis). Unfortunately, the little functional analysis I know is self taught so I am not sure how to construct such a proof/generalization and wanted to ask for some help.

In finite dimension my argument is quite simply. The inner product $ \langle a, b \rangle$ in finite dimensions is just a dot product: $ a \cdot b = a^T b$. Therefore, we get the following series of equalities:

$ \langle Ux, t \rangle = ( Ux)^T t = x^T U^T t = x^T (U^T t) = x^T (U^{-1} t) = \langle x, U^{-1}t \rangle $

Which makes sense for unitary matrix since its definition is $ U^{T} U = U^{T} U  = I $ which for square matrices implies $U^{T} = U^{-1}$ (I guess more precisely, it was for orthonormal matrices, that are square). However, a similar argument doesn't seem to generalize to nicely infinite vectors if one defines the inner product to be an integral (I know the notion of inner product is more general, but wasn't sure how to use the more general notion to prove the equality I want, so I tried the most natural extension of my finite dimensional knowledge):

$$ \langle Ux, t \rangle = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (U \cdot x)(\tau) t(\tau) d\tau$$

where $ (U \cdot x)(\tau) $ is the unitary transformation acting on $x$ a the point $(\tau)$.

Now I have a few questions:

1. Is there a similar proof to what I had using the definition of the inner product as an integral?
2. Is this even the right way to think about it? Or should this equality hold even for **any** definition of an inner product?
3. Or is $\langle Ux, t \rangle = \langle x, U^{-1}t \rangle$ just the definition of a unitary transformation and (sadly) there is no way to "derive it" as I did in the finite dimensional case?

Comment: The usual definition of "unitary" is that the adjoint of the operator is also the inverse of the operator, $U^*=U^{-1}$. Plug that into the defining property of adjoints, $\langle Ux,t\rangle=\langle x,U^* t\rangle$ and you get the equation you wanted.  (Technicality: Since unitary operators are bounded, you don't have any of the worries about domains of operators and their adjoints that otherwise afflict infinite-dimensional Hilbert space operator theory.)

Comment: What is your definition of "unitary"?  It doesn't make sense to ask why $\langle Ux, t \rangle = \langle x, U^{-1}t \rangle$ without knowing what "unitary" even means to begin with...